# How to test HostListener window scroll on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, jasmine

I'm having difficulties to test this function and both conditions, does anyone can help?

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(event: Event) {
    const numb = window.scrollY;
    if (numb >= 50){
        this.scrolled = true;
    }
    else {
        this.scrolled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's even to test in this function. ?

Comment: if the variable scrolled is true or false based on the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend injecting the window by doing something like:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) {
  this.window = this.document.defaultView;
}

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll(event: Event) {
  this.scrolled = this.window.scrollY >= 50;
}
```

Then, assuming you are using something like Jasmine/Karma to write your tests, in your spec you can inject the window and dispatch fake scroll events to test the response.

```
let mockWindow: any;
beforeEach(() => {
  mockWindow = document.createElement('div');
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: { defaultView: mockWindow } }]
  });
});

it('responds to scroll events' () => {
  Object.defineProperty(mockWindow, 'scrollY', { value: 100 });
  mockWindow.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
  expect(fixture.componentInstance.scrolled).toBe(true);
});
```

Here I have also faked the scrollY with defineProperty in order to make the tests sane.

Caveat:
I have not done this with the `@HostListener('window:scroll')`, but it has worked for me using `@HostListener('window:resize')` so I imagine it will work similarly. I wrote this all freehand, so I wouldn't expect it to run perfectly if copy/pasted.